# Change host IP of master in mysql replication

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave-replication

I have one master and one slave. Suppose IP of master is changed but the physical server is same. Now I want to update the new IP (of the master) at the slave server. At the slave server `master_info_repository` is set to `TABLE`. I want to resume the replication process from exactly the position where it has paused due to IP change. How to do this? mysql version of slave server is : `14.14 Distrib 5.7.30` and O/S is `ubuntu 18.04`.

Answer (score 6):

After a long internet surfing I got a thing. `MASTER_LOG_FILE` will take `Relay_Master_Log_File` and `MASTER_LOG_POS` will take `Exec_Master_Log_Pos` as their respective value in `CHANGE MASTER TO` statement. In the [Exec_Master_Log_Pos section of mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-slave-status.html) it is clearly stated. I have found another [article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/07/07/how-show-slave-status-relates-to-change-master-to/) which says the same thing :

> When you’re using CHANGE MASTER TO to set start position for the slave
> you’re specifying position for SQL thread and so you should use
> Relay_Master_Log_File:Exec_Master_Log_Pos. Otherwise you’re going to
> ruin your replication.

> It does not help SHOW MASTER STATUS has Master_Log_File value and
> CHANGE MASTER TO accepts Master_Log_File parameter, while you actually
> want to use Relay_Master_Log_File instead. This naming was left from
> pre MySQL 4.0 era and it still causes confusion so many years later.

**Conclusion :**

1. `STOP SLAVE;`
2. `SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G`
3. note down `Relay_Master_Log_File` value (Example : mysql-bin.000007) and `Exec_Master_Log_Pos` value (Example : 775)
4. `CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='<New IP of Master>', MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000007', MASTER_LOG_POS=775;`
5. `START SLAVE;`

Comment: Thanks you! It's working solution.

Answer (score 1):

As you only want to change the ip and it is the same server

On the slave you run

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS
```

then you copy

```
Relay_Master_Log_File for example mysql-bin.000001
Exec_Master_Log_Pos for example 111111
```

then you stop the slave

```
STOP SLAVE;

CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='192.168.1.1',
MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001', MASTER_LOG_POS=111111;

START SLAVE;
```

`192.168.1.1` is of course only a example

uf you need to change more things, please look at the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/change-master-to.html)

Comment: The link you referred says that : **If you specify the MASTER_HOST or MASTER_PORT option, the replica assumes that the source is different from before (even if the option value is the same as its current value.) In this case, the old values for the source's binary log file name and position are considered no longer applicable, so if you do not specify MASTER_LOG_FILE and MASTER_LOG_POS in the statement, MASTER_LOG_FILE='' and MASTER_LOG_POS=4 are silently appended to it.**. I stopped slave, then delete tables from master, then changed IP of master, then applied your method. I saw error.

Comment: Cause of error : Slave started with log position 4. At log position 4 those tables were exist in master. So slave tried to create those tables at slave and faced error **tables are already exist**.

Comment: i am sorry the log file and the position ahave to be read ´before you stopped it, so the default values are wrong.

Comment: I need some elaboration on your method. I am no pro in DB. If you use **Relay** log then why why don't you use **Relay** log pos??

Comment: See the accepted answer - you should use `Exec_Master_Log_Pos` not `Read_Master_Log_Pos`.